# "con" meaning in The Japense podcast "nihongo con teppei"

Tags: translation, word-usage

Hey just wanted a quick clarification for "Con" in this podcast tite. Does it mean "Japanese with Teppei"? sorry I don't know the exact script for "con" as it wasn't provided on the site.

https://nihongoconteppei.com/

Comment: The podcast owner is a Japanese person who learned Spanish, so I believe you're right about *con* meaning *with*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because unfortunately, it's not really a question about Japanese at all.

Comment: Well the Podcast is about learning Japanese, and I wasn't sure if his title was completely in Japanese or not as it was pointed out to me that the "con" is spanish for "with" But Nihongo 日本語 Is clearly japanese. so you can understand my confusion but this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guy is using the Spanish word "con" which means "with".

"Nihongo con Teppei" => "Japanese with Teppei"